# how to reduce the log which the skywalking agent send to service

Tags: java, skywalking

The log which the skywalking agent send to service is too large, how can I reduce it, and which config file can be updated to make it ?

Answer (score -1):

SkyWalking's log reporter is log framework based. For example, in log4j, https://skywalking.apache.org/docs/main/v8.7.0/en/setup/service-agent/java-agent/application-toolkit-log4j-1.x/#grpc-reporter

`log4j.rootLogger=INFO,CustomAppender  log4j.appender.CustomAppender=org.apache.skywalking.apm.toolkit.log.log4j.v1.x.log.GRPCLogClientAppender log4j.appender.CustomAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout log4j.appender.CustomAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n`

You could send the logger to match which logs you want to send out.